# How to determine operantors between given numbers to get a given result

Tags: arithmetic

In a children's math book I found the following example:

> There are $2$ numbers: $242, 961$.
>
> You can use these numbers as many times
>   as you want, and you can use any arithmetical operator between them. E.g.: $242+242*961-961$
>
> The result must be $562$.

One should determine the how these numbers can be used with any arithmetical operator to give the result.
Which is the best way to solve it?

I tried it with Wolfram but didn't know how to supply these values to it. Is there a regular way to solve these types of tasks?

Do you have any hint?

Comment: you want a $2$-ary function $f$ such that $f(242,961)=562$?

Comment: So you're expecting a "children's answer"? Is gcd allowed?

Comment: @MphLee the function has two inputs and has to have that result. You can use the inputs many times.

Comment: @user88595 Everything is allowed.

Comment: The extended Euclidean algorithm (look it up!) will find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $$242a-961b=562$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a children's answer but a sure way of getting there is by considering the gcd:

$$gcd(961, 242) = 1$$

Hence you can find $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb Z$ such that: $$961x + 242y = 1$$
Multiply both sides by the required value, $562$ in your case and you obtain:
$$961\cdot562x + 242\cdot 562y = 562$$

So by repetitive addition and subtraction of $961$ and of $241$, you can get there.

Use Euclid's algorithm and go backwards to get $x = 69$ and $y=-274$.

Comment: Well, I never used the extended Euclidean algorithm, and I can't see the result yet. I'll try.

Comment: @Nestor: I've just edited it. If you've never tried it, I suggest you first try with smaller numbers.